# UINavigationController without NavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a "landing page/view" that I dont want the navigation bar to show, so I turn it off during the viewDidAppear

```
navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

When i push a view on the stack and then move it off. the main landing page shows the nav bar then hides it which cause a flicker that I dont want.

is there a way to have the landing page be a UIView or something? When a menu item is touched the app would push a new view on top of the default landing page. It sound like it would be hard to do without having the landing page be a UINavigationController. Any thoguhts?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to go back to the landing page, use a view controller for the landing page and present it modally from the navigation controller when the application starts.

---

So you do want to go back to the landing page.

It's hard to accomplish that with `UINavigationController`. Suppose your are going back to the landing view. While the transition, the old view should have a navigation bar, and the new view (landing page) should not have a navigation bar. `UINavigationController` does not allow you manually modifying the transition animation. In other words, you cannot animate hiding/unhiding the navigation bar along with push/pop animation (using `viewWillAppear` doesn't solve the problem).

So what would I do, if I really, really need this?

I would have a rootViewController (of `UIViewController`), whose view is the only subview of your application window. When your application starts, `rootViewController` add the landing view as a subview of its view. When the user selects an item there, you create an `UINavigationController` with the corresponding view controller as its root view controller.

And, using `CATransition` animation with type of `kCATransitionPush` and subtype of `kCATransitionFromRight`, you add the view of the navigation controller as a subview of `rootViewController`'s view.

Then you need a 'back' button for the first view of the navigation controller. In all view controllers that are the first level view controllers of the navigation controller, create a bar button item with a text 'Back', and add it to their `navigationItem.leftBarButton` property. Set a target-action (probably to the `rootViewController`) pair for the button.

When the action message fires, use `CATransition` animation (now with `kCATransitionFromLeft` subtype), to remove the current navigation controller's view from `rootViewController`'s view.

The transition may not look as perfect as the native `UINavigationController`, but I believe this is the best you could get.

Comment: I do want to go back to the main landing page because it acts as a main menu. but i dont want the navbar to show and I dont want to hide it as it reappears becuase it look funny when it is being hidden.

Comment: Edited the answer for more suggestions.

Comment: After testing it myself, I found this works quite well. I would consider polishing it and using it in many cases :).

Answer (score 1):

Try hiding the navigation bar in viewWillAppear, rather than viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the way to do this is to implement UINavigationController's delegate method `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated`. This method is where you should handle hiding and showing your navigation bar so the animation will occur *during* the push/pop animation.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a method that is simple and works well for me, and is not given here yet. I assume you have a view controller for the main landing page and it is set as root view controller of the navigation controller. Then you should hide/show the navigation bar in the viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods of the main landing page controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Source:
http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/